# overloading augmented arithmetic assignments in python

Tags: python, operators, operator-overloading

I'm new to Python so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

For an assignment I need to overload augmented arithmetic assignments(+=, -=, /=, *=, **=, %=) for a class myInt. I checked the Python documentation and this is what I came up with:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):

    if isinstance(other, myInt):
        self.a += other.a
    elif type(other) == int:
        self.a += other
    else:
        raise Exception("invalid argument")
```

self.a and other.a refer to the int stored in each class instance. I tried testing this out as follows, but each time I get 'None' instead of the expected value 5:

```
c = myInt(2)
b = myInt(3)
c += b
print c
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe there are no stupid questions..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add `return self` to your method.  Explanation:

The semantics of `a += b`, when `type(a)` has a special method `__iadd__`, are defined to be:

```
  a = a.__iadd__(b)
```

so if `__iadd__` returns something different than `self`, that's what will be bound to name `a` after the operation.  By missing a `return` statement, the method you posted is equivalent to one with `return None`.

Comment: Alex,I always love your answers!

Answer (score 7):

Augmented operators in Python have to return the final value to be assigned to the name they are called on, usually (and in your case) `self`. Like all Python methods, missing a return statement implies returning `None`.

Also,

- Never ever ever raise `Exception`, which is impossible to catch sanely. The code to do so would have to say `except Exception`, which will catch *all* exceptions. In this case you want `ValueError` or `TypeError`.
- Don't typecheck with `type(foo) == SomeType`. In this (and virtually all) cases, `isinstance` works better or at least the same.
- Whenever you make your own type, like `myInt`, you should name it with capital letters so people can recognize it as a class name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need "return self", it will look like this:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, myInt):
        self.a += other.a
        return self
    elif type(other) == int:
        self.a += other
        return self
    else:
        raise Exception("invalid argument")
```

Comment: Also, you should make your `Exception` a `TypeError`.